# Аутентификация сторонних сервисов

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, аутентификация

Всем привет, у меня имеется клиент серверное приложение на приложение на Asp.net core помимо основного проекта, появилась необходимость добавить проект WEB API с которым будут работать другие сервисы (т е не клиенты с браузером).

Вопрос в следующем: Если сервис при первом обращении прошел аутентификацию по логину паролю, как хранить информацию о том что сервис аутентифицирован, для клиентской части используются обычные куки, я не знаю смогут ли сторонние сервисы хранить куки.

Если конкретезировать вопрос: Какие временные данные (куки, токены, Id сессии) может хранить сторонний сервис и как их передавать, постоянно в параметры обработчика запроса или в заголовках HTTP или как то еще?

Comment: Можно вместо логина пароля - одни ключ. Всеравно что логин-пароль что ключ - без разницы. Можно не хранить - при каждом запросе требовать передать ключ (логин пароль).

Comment: Поглядите в сторону token-based аутентификации